# Blocking websites by syncing Android with desktop

Tags: sync

I know of an app, Blocksite, that allows users to block websites by syncing their Android phone with their desktop. But to do so you must install Blocksite on Android, which can easily be uninstalled. Is there any way to sync a blocking app on Android and the desktop which does not need to be downloaded on the phone? In other words, you download it on the desktop only and it also blocks websites on your phone once you sync it. Or is there any other way to control apps on your phone through your desktop to block websites so you must access your desktop to unblock them? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not possible. You can try Google's Digital Wellbeing to block and set timers on the websites. But there's no desktop version available to use.

From my experience, If you block a website for at least two weeks with an app. You can control yourself for the third week without the help of an app.

I would like to recommend Freedom (https://freedom.to) instead of Blocksite. It's paid one. But worth it.